# update height of iframe on chrome (android)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, iframe

We have javascript widget which dynamically loads an iFrame to display external content. When iframe have loaded or it's content have resized it send message via **postMessage**. Widget get a message and resize iframe:

```js
iframe.style.height = msg.value + 'px';
```

It works correctly on most browsers except chrome 50 on Android 5.0. Besides this code don't work on Windows Mobile Emulator on browserstack. I tried to change property and attribute:

```js
iframe.setAttribute("height", msg.value + 'px');
iframe.height = msg.value;
iframe.style.height = msg.value + 'px';
```

But it doesn't work.

After height has changed  I checked it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(iframe.style.height)
},
10000);
```

Alert shown that iframe's height has changed but iframe hasn't resized on page.

I don't understand how resolve it. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was css styles. I have set `!important` property:

```
iframe.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' +  msg.value + 'px !important');
```

And then it works.